# How can I combine NDSolve[] with NSolve[]

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Consider the two below ODEs with following dependent B.C.  In the boundary conditions $k$ is an unknown.

$$y_1''(x)=x$$
$$y_2''(y)=0$$
$$y_1(1)=y_2(1)$$
$$y_1(-k)=y_2(-k)$$
$$\frac{\text{dy}_1(1)}{\text{dx}}=\frac{\text{dy}_2(1)}{\text{dx}}$$
$$\frac{\text{dy}_1(-k)}{\text{dx}}=\frac{\text{dy}_2(-k)}{\text{dx}}$$
$$\int_0^k {{y_2}\left( x \right)} dx = k$$
In this case, in order to find all unknowns, first, DSolve[] is used to solve the ODEs. Second, B.C. is applied to create 5 equations and unknowns. At the end, NSolve[] is implied to solve the system of equation with 5 unknowns. Following code is what I explained.

```
odey1 = DSolveValue[y1''[x] == x, y1[x], x];
odey2 = DSolveValue[y2''[y] == 0, y2[y], y] /. {C[1] -> C[3], 
    C[2] -> C[4]};
eqn1 = (odey1 /. x -> 1) == (odey2 /. y -> 1);
eqn2 = (odey1 /. x -> -k) == (odey2 /. y -> -k);
eqn3 = ((D[odey1, x]) /. x -> 1) == ((D[odey2, y]) /. y -> 1);
eqn4 = ((D[odey1, x]) /. x -> -k) == ((D[odey2, y]) /. y -> -k);
eqn5 = Integrate[odey2, {y, 0, k}] == k

coef = NSolve[
  eqn1 && eqn2 && eqn3 && eqn4 && eqn5, {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], k}]
odey1 /. coef;
odey2 /. coef;
```

> {{C[1] -> -7.95938*10^15 + 5.84722*10^15 I,    C[2] -> -2.92835*10^15
>   + 1.97798*10^15 I,    C[3] -> -7.95938*10^15 + 5.84722*10^15 I,    C[4] -> -2.92835*10^15 + 1.97798*10^15 I,    k -> -4.88246 + 1.65421
>   I}, {C[1] -> 
>      8.65911*10^11 - 7.14483*10^11 I,    C[2] -> 3.70956*10^11 - 2.62275*10^11 I,    C[3] -> 8.65911*10^11 - 7.14483*10^11 I,    C[4] -> 3.70956*10^11 - 2.62275*10^11 I,    k -> -5.03678 + 0.40725 I}, {C[1] -> -2.25067*10^10 - 
>       1.96804*10^10 I, C[2] -> 5.21094*10^9 - 1.92651*10^9 I,    C[3] -> -2.25067*10^10 - 1.96804*10^10 I,    C[4] -> 5.21094*10^9 - 1.92651*10^9 I,    k -> 5.50713 + 9.1575 I}, {C[1] -> 4441.08 + 1806.41 I,    C[2] -> 8880.03 + 3613.21 I, C[3] -> 4440.75 + 1806.41 I,    C[4] -> 8880.53 + 3613.21 I, k -> -0.99988 - 2.69101*10^-6 I}}

My real case is much complicated and the ODEs doesn’t have close form. Therefore, I have to use NDSolve[] for solving ODEs. In this case I don’t know how can I combine NDSolve[] with NSolve[] to find the unknowns C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4] 
        and $k$.

I will appreciate, if somebody can help me.

Comment: You will probably have to use `FindRoot`.  If only one solution is sought, it is probably the way to go.  If you seek several solutions, then it might not; might depend on the actual problem.  BTW, `NDSolve[]` implements a shooting method for BVPs -- would that work for your actual problem?

Comment: After looking more closely, I don't think the shooting method is set up to deal with such complicated BCs. -- You have some ells `l` in your code which I suspect are supposed to be ones `1`. Is that right?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your respond. I have modified the problem to have the solution. The problem that I presented before was a hypothetical example. Now, with current example do you have any Idea how can I change DSolve[] with NDSolve? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preamble

After solving the differential equations it appears that there are five equations with five unknowns (four generated from the two differential equations and the parameter `k`.

However there are only four pieces of information in the five equations so there still is one arbitrary constant.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many routes that lead to this conclusion, perhaps the easiest to see is as follows. Since `y''[x]=0` this implies that `y'[x]` is a constant. This means that the right hand side of *eqns3* and *eqns4* are identical.

As a result *eqns3* and *eqns4* collapse into one equation where the left hand sides are now equal.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### DSolve - boundary conditions

The equations will be re-written so that two boundary conditions (*eqn1* and *eqn3*) will be incorporated into the equations. The motivation for this is to pave the way for a numerical solution.

The boundary conditions for the main function and its derivative are set at `x = 1` and are equated to the arbitrary constants `a` and `b`.

```
odc1 = DSolveValue[{y1''[x] == x, y1[1] == a, y1'[1] == b}, y1[x], x]
(* 1/6 (2 + 6 a - 6 b - 3 x + 6 b x + x^3) *)

odc2 = DSolveValue[{y2''[x] == 0, y2[1] == a, y2'[1] == b}, y2[x], x]
(* a - b + b x *)
```

I find it useful to create functions for the solutions and (later) the derivatives.

```
yc1[x_, a_, b_] := (2 + 6 (a - b) + (6 b - 3 ) x + x^3)/6
yc2[x_, a_, b_] := a + b (x - 1)
```

Next take the derivative of `yc1` and `yc2`.

```
D[yc1[x, a, b], x]
(* 1/6 (-3 + 6 b + 3 x^2) *)

D[yc2[x, a, b], x]
(* b *)
```

Observe that the derivative of `yc2` is a constant. Again this is why two of the equations collapse.

Functions are defined for the derivatives

```
dyc1[x_, a_, b_] := (2 b - 1 + x^2)/2
dyc2[x_, a_, b_] := b
```

Next the other three equations are written. *eqc1* is set to the condition where the two solutions are equated at `x = -k`.

```
eqc1 = yc1[-k, a, b] == yc2[-k, a, b]
(* 1/6 (2 + 6 (a - b) - (-3 + 6 b) k - k^3) == a + b (-1 - k) *)
```

*eqc2* is set to the condition where the two derivates are equated at `x = -k`.

```
eqc2 = dyc1[-k, a, b] == dyc2[-k, a, b]
(* 1/2 (-1 + 2 b + k^2) == b *)
```

*eqc3* is set to the condition where the integral is equated to `k`

```
Integrate[yc2[x, a, b], {x, 0, k}]
(* a k - b k + (b k^2)/2 *)

eqc3 = (a - b ) k + (b k^2)/2 == k;
```

Next solve these three equations allowing `a` to be an arbitrary constant

```
Solve[{eqc1, eqc2, eqc3}, {b, k}]
(* {{b -> 2/3 (-1 + a), k -> -1}} *)
```

The solution shows a relationship between `a` and `b`. `k` is found to be -1.

A second form for the functions `yc1` and `yc2` are created that honor the solution and only take the `a` parameter.

```
yc1[x_, a_] := Module[
  {
   b = (2 (a - 1))/3
   },
  (2 + 6 (a - b) + (6 b - 3 ) x + x^3)/6
  ]

yc2[x_, a_] := Module[
  {
   b = (2 (a - 1))/3
   },
  a + b (x - 1)
  ]
```

The function has the same name as the original but is distinct because of only two arguments.

Below is a plot for three values of `a`.

```
Plot[{yc1[x, -1], yc1[x, 0], yc1[x, 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{yc2[x, -1], yc2[x, 0], yc2[x, 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Numerical Solution

We will attempt to do follow the same steps as above but use a numerical solver. In order to allow the differential equation to accept non-numerical parameters it is necessary to use `ParametricNDSolve`.

```
opc1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y1''[x] == x, y1[1] == a, y1'[1] == b},
   y1, {x, -5, 5}, {a, b}]
opc2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y2''[x] == 0, y2[1] == a, y2'[1] == b},
   y2, {x, -5, 5}, {a, b}]
```

The output is a `ParametricFunction` that we can use downstream. Functions are defined that require numerical inputs (again, needed later).

```
ynp1[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := opc1[a, b][x]
ynp2[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := opc2[a, b][x]
```

Here are the derivates

```
dynp1[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := opc1[ a, b]'[x]
ynp2[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := opc2[ a, b]'[x]
```

For the integral we will define a numerical form

```
int2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[ynp2[x, a, b], {x, 0, k}]
```

By trial and error I found that `FindRoot` wanted the a function as an input rather than `lhs == rhs`.

The functions are described by taking the difference between the left and right hand sides.

```
eqd1 = ynp1[-k, a, b] - ynp2[-k, a, b]
eqd2 = dynp1[-k, a, b] - dynp2[-k, a, b]
eqd3 = int2[a, b, k] - k
```

`FindMinimum` worked by asking it to minimize the sum of the squares of the above expressions but the parameters `a` was set to an arbitrary constant (unity for this example). Surprisingly `FindMinimum` would not accept `eqd1` through `eqd3`, one had to manually insert the corresponding expression.

```
sol = FindMinimum[
  (ynp1[-k, 1, b] - ynp2[-k, 1, b])^2 +
   (dynp1[-k, 1, b] - dynp2[-k, 1, b])^2 +
   (int2[1, b, k] - k)^2,
  {{b, -1}, {k, -1}}
  ]

(* {1.97215*10^-31, {b -> 9.73186*10^-16, k -> -1.}} *)
```

`FindRoot` was a bit fussy in that it complained if the number of equations and unknowns were not identical. *eqd1* was replaced with the statement substracting `a` from the desired value. Interesting that `FindRoot` happily accepted `eqd2` and `eqd3`.

```
FindRoot[
 {
  a - 1,
  eqd2,
  eqd3
  },
 {{a, 1}, {b, 0}, {k, -1}}
 ]
(* {a -> 1., b -> 0., k -> -1.} *)
```

Both of these results match the `DSolve`.

A function to plot `ynp1` with the solution constants can be defined as:

```
plotYp1[astart_?NumericQ, color_] := Module[
  {
   sol = FindMinimum[
     (ynp1[-k, astart, b] - ynp2[-k, astart, b])^2 +
      (dynp1[-k, astart, b] - dynp2[-k, astart, b])^2 +
      (int2[astart, b, k] - k)^2,
     {{b, -1}, {k, -1}}
     ]
   },

  Plot[(ynp1[x, astart, b] /. sol[[2]]), {x, -3, 3},
   PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-2, 4.65}},
    PlotStyle -> color]
  ]
```

And a duplicate of the `DSolve` plot is made.

```
Show[
 plotYp1[-1, Blue],
 plotYp1[0, Black],
 plotYp1[1, Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similar results apply for the second function:

```
plotYp2[astart_?NumericQ, color_] := Module[
  {
   sol = FindMinimum[
     (ynp1[-k, astart, b] - ynp2[-k, astart, b])^2 +
      (dynp1[-k, astart, b] - dynp2[-k, astart, b])^2 +
      (int2[astart, b, k] - k)^2,
     {{b, -1}, {k, -1}}
     ]
   },

  Plot[(ynp2[x, astart, b] /. sol[[2]]), {x, -3, 3},
   PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-2, 4.65}},
    PlotStyle -> color]
  ]

Show[
 plotYp2[-1, Blue],
 plotYp2[0, Black],
 plotYp2[1, Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps you with your actual problem. Good luck!

Comment: I really appreciate you. Your answer is so professional. I am trying to digest what you did and implement your procedure to my actual problem. Thanks a lot.